# Extract the file type and use it like VSCode

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

VS code has a feature where icons are displayed next to the file name in the folder panel. As shown in the example below.

[image]

I would like to know how to implement an extension detection function like VSCode's one.

The problem I faced dealing with files having multiple types. For example, a `.tsconfig.json` file would be problematic. This is because you could have a file with the name `index.index.tsconfig.json`, which will enforce the use of a loop to detect it appropriately as it contains more than one type, but the icon would only change in accordance with the last type/two types.

This is what I mean:

[image]

Here, the types `index`, `cc` and `js` are ignored. The icon only changed according to the last `tsconfig.json`.

The file types are gonna be in a JSON file, inside an array. What is a method to determine the type of the file according to the last types only?

Comment: Just curious, how a json can be a typescript?

Comment: test the most specific first, is file `README.md` then, end with `.tsconfig.json`, later the more generic, end with `.json`